# Условные операторы pymongo

Tags: pymongo

```
db.collection.find({'user_id': {$eq : message.from_user.id}})
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ругается на **`$`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поздно, но ладно

```py
dp.collection.find({'user_id': {"$eq": message.from_user.id})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]